# Find sum of radii of possible circles passing through $\left(a, \frac {1}{a}\right)$

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ represent the radii of the smallest and the largest circle passing through $(a, \frac {1}{a})$
and touching the circle $$4x^2+4y^2-4x-8y-31=0$$ where $a$ is the least possible value of the ratio of sides of the regular $n$ sided polygon($n\ge 3$) inscribed and circumscribed to a unit circle then find the the value of $r_1+r_2$

**My work**:-

The side of the n sided polygon whose inradius is $1$ is $$\tan {\frac {\pi}{n}}$$ and the side of $n$ sided polygon if the circumradius is $1$ is $$\sin {\frac {\pi}{n}}$$
For the value of $a$ we need to find the minimum value of $$\sec \frac{\pi}{n}$$ 
Now for the circle to be the largest one, the given circle must touch it internally while the smallest circle must touch it externally.  But using this logic I am getting the wrong answer. Can someone please provide a bit better approach to such problem.

Comment: How odd and frankly un-natural is this question !

Comment: Is this question a very bad one.  Even if it is please explain me your solution

Comment: Once the value of $a$ has been found, the problem simply boils down to computing the distance between $(a,1/a)$ and $(1/2,1)$, i.e. the center of the first circle (having radius $3$).

Comment: @Manthanein: I will do that if you clarify the definition of $a$. $\sec\frac{\pi}{n}$ does not attain its minimum at $n=4$. Indeed, it has ho minimum.

Comment: I have posted the question as it was given in my sheet to solve as a test. I too had the same doubt about a so I posted this question here.

Comment: Did anyone get any clue yet.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{\text{side of the $n$-sided regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle}
\over
\text{side of the $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribed to a unit circle}}
=\cos{\pi\over n},
$$
the minimum $a={1\over2}$ being attained for $n=3$.

As the given circle has center $\big({1\over2},1\big)$ and radius $3$, the smallest and the largest circle passing through $(a,1/a)$ and touching the circle have diameters of $2$ and $4$ respectively.